# How to keep click event dynamically created buttons in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i have retrive name of buttons from database those button when i click a 
   button i need to show the some report.now i have everything is done.i 
   need to know how keep unique id for those buttons and how they worked 
   when i click button i need to show report in a separate page...

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Estate()
        {

            return View("Estate", new EstateFunc().Estates());

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Estate(int id=0)
        {
            if(id>0)
            {

            }
            return View();

         }
```

Comment: What do you want to use for the click handler? jQuery or call an action/controller?

Comment: call an action/controller

Answer (score 0):

With MVC

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Something...</td>
        <td>@item.AnotherThing</td>
        <td>
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { Id = item.Id })" class="btn"></a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

This Razor code will generate as many button as the count of the collection items in your model. Every item in the collection should have unique ID and as you see we put this ID as parameter. So when the user clicks on any of the buttons, the unique ID will tell us which button was clicked (and to which item we should refer to)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id = 0)
        {
            var model = ReportViewModel(id);

            return ReportView(model);
        }

private ReportViewModel(int id)
{
   // Get Report from Database Where Id = id
   // Populate ViewModel from the database data
   // Return reportViewModel;
}
```

EDIT (adding example based on your code)

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <div class="floated">

    <a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { Id = item.Id })" 
       class="Estates_button">@item.EstateName</a>

    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you check above code which i added now ,can you rewrite above code what i want to do

Comment: ok, I updated my post. Simply put my line of code and replace your <input>. But still you will need to have unique ID for each item to know which button was clicked.

Comment: Can you help me that also how to keep unique id those buttons pls and how to check if conditon which button click

Comment: Post your controller code on your question. Also - what is your model? Does it come from database table? Do you have primary key (unique identifier)? Also explain in your question what should this button click do?

Comment: Hi i add the controller code i exaplain as well what i want to do pleas help me yes coming from database i have primary key autoid when i click a button i need to show the report in the diffrent page

Comment: In my example: new { Id = item.Id } Id should be your DB AutoID (the model property that maps the AutoID).

Comment: Can you help me out how to use above code in the controller how to write if condition those button which button i click

Comment: You don't need If condition. Just take the ID and go to the DB and grab the report data, then convert it into ViewModel and pass that to the Report View

Comment: See my answer. The example is there. Also remove the [HttpPost] attribute from your controller.